# How does the Xbox Series X "Heat-sink chassis" work?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, airflow, cooling, heatsink

I understand what a heatsink does, but I cannot wrap my head around how the newly announced Xbox Series X's heat-sink chassis works. From [Xbox](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/consoles/xbox-series-x?&ef_id=CjwKCAjwsMzzBRACEiwAx4lLGw4_-dzkecsu7yo-wVffHHtZCipIx5eNgPnYJLLlWrBq5cTQTn2BsRoC7YAQAvD_BwE:G:s&OCID=AID2000034_SEM_ZTFFI6uc):

> Heat-sink chassis
>
> A heat sink is a non-electronic, passive mechanical component that has a vital role in the reliability and performance of the Xbox Series X and is integrated directly into the chassis of the console. This unique component of the parallel cooling architecture helps lend to the distinctive design of the console.

[image]

The reason it perplexes me is because it seems to be lacking two main factors to be a heatsink. It does not have rows of fins or spikes to maximize surface area to the air, and it does not appear to maximize the surface area in contact with the hottest sections of the circuit boards (GPU/CPU). Is this just marketing fluff?

Comment: A large flat plate will dissipate the same amount as a finned heatsink if the area is the same (keeping other factors equivalent)

Comment: The areas of the board getting hot will be quite concentrated - this will spread that out quite well.

Comment: The heatsink only touches the circuit board at the perimeter. How is this cooling the hottest component the CPU/GPU?